# bluemix. My first application and a montain of doubts

Tags: sql, ibm-cloud

I would like to understand bluemix better. How I can create my first application using the bluemix platform? For example: Until now, I know that one application uses a graphic interface to interact with the client, and another application that will communicate with the data base to search the information that our client needs. But for a beginner (as me) what is the best graphic interface that I can use? The database used in my system is the DB2. What the service could I use to create the sql queries to search the information that I need?

Comment: Hello, Stackoverflow is a programming community.  General questions about how to do xyz without code are generally not well received questions and will probably be closed.  Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to write a good question.  Please rephrase your question.  Additionally your question is quite large, not a single specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading some books on building web applications in a language of your interest. Java is popular... I would start with something like "Beginning Java EE 7", and then start with some of the boilerplates on Bluemix such as [Java DB Web Starter](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/java-db-web-starter/)